# Tense usage with dead writers' work

Tags: tenses, present-tense

My friend and I discussed some books and their authors the other day. And the question arose. Is it possible to say

Do you like what he **writes** about?

using Present Simple, although writer did that in the past and he is already dead?

Comment: Yes, it often happens that way. When one reads an author's work, one hears the author's voice, and it doesn't really matter if they're dead; as long as you can hear them in your mind's ear, they're present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Do you like what he writes about?*

This is an example of the *[historical present](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/historical+present)*:

> n.   The present tense used in the narration of events set in the
>   past.
>
> When telling stories about past events, people often switch into
>   present tense, as in I was walking home from work one day. All of a
>   sudden this man comes up to me and says.... This phenomenon, called
>   the historical present, has a long history in English and is found in
>   numerous other languages, both ancient and modern. Linguists have
>   sometimes suggested that the historical present makes stories more
>   vivid primarily by bringing past actions into the immediate present.
>
> thefreedictionary.com

*[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)* refers to Geoffrey Leech's *Meaning and the English Verb*, noting that the *historical present* tense is often used for verbs of communication:

> **In conversation**, it is particularly common with 'verbs of
>   communication' such as tell, write, and say (and in colloquial uses,
>   go) (Leech 2002: 7).
>
> **Emphasis** mine

Since we **experience** the past activity of the author's writing in the present activity of reading, it feels just as natural to refer to the writing in the present tense.

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. Thank you for accurate term. In my language I would use present tense in this sentense too and no one consider me to be an illiterate one because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I tend to be fairly literal in how I speak with people.  I would be more prone to use the term, "wrote" versus, "write" unless the author is still actively writing about the subject at hand.  Ex: writing another book, novel,or poem in a series.

Answer (score 1):

If it is well known that the author is dead, then "he wrote about" would be my choice. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare for example.

If the author is contemporary, where we assume he is still living (and still writing) then "he writes about" may be better, even though he may be dead or a few books may be ready for publication posthumously.  An example here may be Tom Clancy.

If the author is still living, but we know that he is not actively writing, then "he used to write about" may be another choice. An example may be Philip Roth here.

I guess it depends on our knowledge of the state of author.

EDIT In response to a comment by @casey :
When a search for "shakespeare writes" is given to google, it auto-corrects or suggests "shakespeare wrote"  which is not much to go by, but indicates the more "common" form :
[image: auto - correct]
It seems that "shakespeare wrote" is more common in general, while "shakespeare writes" is used in newspaper style & biographical or historical reporting.

Comment: "Shakespeare writes" [is well-attested](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shakespeare%20writes%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1904,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en).

Comment: @Casey , I have responded to your comment by updating the answer !

Answer (score 0):

If there is a doubt, it is best avoided, because someone else (such as me) will find it jars. Here it is easily avoided with something like:

> Do you like the subject of his novels?

(Substitute *themes*, *subject matter* etc. for *subject*; and *works*, *articles* etc. for *novels*, as appropriate).

This also avoids the rather awkward preposition at the end of the sentence. (Yes, I know the Churchill quote, but in this case I find the terminal preposition inelegant.)

Comment: Inelegance is in the ear of the auditor.

Comment: Indeed, I'll modify my comment to indicate that the remark is subjective. However I imagine there is a psychological explanation for my response. The short preposition seems to have been spat out with an emphasis that has no linguistic function, whereas in the alternative the pitch of the sentence subsides gradually, ending in balanced manner. Each sentence needs to be judged on its merits. Churchill's "put up with" is preferable to the alternative contortion, and in any case the "with" is softer than the "up" and provides a useful mitigation. But I digress...

Comment: 'What he writes about' sounds fine to my ears.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I suppose it's like music. I prefer Mozart to Stockhausen.

Comment: I'm glad that Vaughan-Williams usually tops the Classic FM charts. There's a degree of objectivity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Classic FM? That's a bit lowbrow. We only listen to the Third Programme.